# using a array list in ios to create a translation app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, translation

I am taking development courses for ios and I was wondering if I wanted to create a translation app would i use a array list to do so? As example code is:-

```
var dictionary = [“talofa”: “hello’, “faafetai”: “thank you”]
print(dictionary[“talofa”])
```

it shows up in the logs as “hello” but there has to be an easier way to do translations otherwise I would be fitting a whole language in a array list?

I also read online that people have been using third party services like google to make a translation app but my language is not on google (Hawaiian) what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what you are using in your example, in swift/objc it is called a dictionary.

Secondly, for such a huge amount of data, I recommend you use some sort of persistent storage. You can use plain text to store the dictionary (like creating a .plist file), but being iOS I would recommend setting up coredata.

CoreData will allow you to store the information on the device, and access it through a data Model.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662331/storing-a-dictionary-in-swift-in-permanent-storage) you can find an example on storing in a file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005342/swift-and-coredata-data-storage) you can find an example on storing in CoreData.

I personally recommend using coredata for such a large quantity of data. Plist files are more suitable for storing low information quantities (like saving some credentials, some settings, etc).

Comment: I am using swift/objC like i told the other alex i am new to all this still learning the ropes thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Bartis So I set up a coredata file I was able store a bunch of different translations how will the user be able to access the files? I want to be able to translate whatever the user asks

Comment: Start from the bottom, get to know how coredata works

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DB for this. You can update it from your server when user will have connection, so you don't need to re-submit your app when you will update your vocabulary.

You can use CoreData as @Alex Bartiş told you or you can try another one which becomes popular: [Realm](https://realm.io/)

Comment: thank you for your help I new to all this it is still a learning process